# Type of arg 1 to keys must be hash error shows on Perl 5.10 but not Perl 5.16

Tags: perl

I keep getting the following error:

**Type of arg 1 to keys must be hash (not hash element)**

at this line:

```
my $command = join(" ", @{$jparams{args}})
  . " -cp " . $jparams{cp}
  . " "     . $jparams{class}
  . " "     . join(" ",
     map {
       ${_} . "=" . qq|"$jparams{params}{$_}"|
     } keys $jparams{params}
  );
```

The error shows on Perl 5.10 but not Perl 5.16. How do I get it to work across both versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```perl
keys $jparams{params}
```

should be

```perl
keys %{ $jparams{params} }
```

---

Your code suffers from code injection bugs.

If the command is passed to `system` (or `exec`), use its multi-argument form.

```perl
my @command = (
   @{ $jparams{ args } },
   -cp => $jparams{ cp },
   $jparams{ class },
   map { "$_=$jparams{ params }{ $_ }" }
      keys %{ $jparams{ params } },
);

system { $command[0] } @command;
```

Not only will this solve the problem, it will avoid needlessly spawning a shell.

But if you do need a shell command for some reason, your code injectiong bugs can be solved using [String::ShellQuote](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::ShellQuote)'s `shell_quote`.

```perl
my @command = (
   @{ $jparams{ args } },
   -cp => $jparams{ cp },
   $jparams{ class },
   map { "$_=$jparams{ params }{ $_ }" }
      keys %{ $jparams{ params } },
);

my $command = shell_quote( @command );
```

Comment: Assuming (risks acknowledged) this is going to become `system($command)`, it might be better to just build an array.  `@command = (...); system(@command)`.

Comment: @Jim Davis, Of course! That would be better, as it would avoid the shell entirely. `shell_quote` comes in useful if you're using backticks, or you want to incorporate the command in something larger (e.g. `$command = "$command 2&>1";`). I have adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You couldn't pass a reference to `keys` until [Perl 5.14](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta#Array-and-hash-container-functions-accept-references), but became an "experimental" warning in [5.20](https://metacpan.org/release/RJBS/perl-5.20.0/view/pod/perldelta.pod#New-Warnings).

You can fix this by dereferencing the hashref:

```
keys %{ $jparams{params} }
```